# Pairwise combination of vector elements in list form in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have my vector as `all_comparisons <- c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4")`

I want to get the non-self pairs of these and I tried

`mapply(c, all_comparisons, all_comparisons, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` which only gives me the self pairs. What do I need to do to get non-self pairs only? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JorisChau This gives me matrix, I want that in list format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `combn(all_comparisons, 2)`?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "T1" "T1" "T1" "T2" "T2" "T3"
[2,] "T2" "T3" "T4" "T3" "T4" "T4"
```

To have everything in a handy list, you could do something like this

```
xy <- as.data.frame(combn(all_comparisons, 2))

sapply(xy, function(x) as.character(x), simplify = FALSE)

$V1
[1] "T1" "T2"

$V2
[1] "T1" "T3"

$V3
[1] "T1" "T4"

$V4
[1] "T2" "T3"

$V5
[1] "T2" "T4"

$V6
[1] "T3" "T4"
```

Or

```
xy <- combn(all_comparisons, 2)
split(t(xy), f = 1:ncol(xy))
```

Comment: Why not just `combn(all_comparisons, 2, simplify = F)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want

```
split(combn(all_comparisons,2),  col(combn(all_comparisons,2)))

$`1`
[1] "T1" "T2"

$`2`
[1] "T1" "T3"

$`3`
[1] "T1" "T4"

$`4`
[1] "T2" "T3"

$`5`
[1] "T2" "T4"

$`6`
[1] "T3" "T4"
```

Comment: Nice, but `combn` can be pretty expensive if `all_comparison` is large.